# Tailwind Color Classes not working properly when applied on click of a button in NextJS & React Vite

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, state, tailwind-css

So I've a component that basically demonstrates the "Text Gradient" effect in Tailwind + React. I have 4 select dropdowns and a "randomize" button. On clicking the button or select anything from the dropdowns, the changes will be previewed.

Now for the first time ever, I'm running into an issue where color classes are not being properly applied. I mean, they DO appear in the className attribute of the  tag - but the classes are rarely implemented on screen. The colors that are not being applied, also don't show up in Dev Tools -> Style Sidebar.

**I've recorded a 2 minute video - here it is: https://streamable.com/3auz04**

As you can see, I try to constantly generate results and most of the time, the text is transparent / no color is applied.

NOW - I know you must think, maybe the classes are faulty? Well no. At any point, if I copy the classes and go over to play.tailwindcss.com - it works.

```
 <h2 class="bg-gradient-to-r from-pink-700 via-yellow-800 to-lime-500 bg-clip-text text-center text-7xl font-bold text-transparent">Whats Up</h2>
```

Here is an example of a class that doesn't work in my PreviewText.jsx - but works on play.tailwindcss.com - basically proving that there's nothing wrong with the Tailwind classes.

Here's my relevant code:

Gradient useState Variable:

```
 const [gradient, setGradient] = useState({
direction: "bg-gradient-to-tl",
fromColor: "from-slate-800",
viaColor: "via-violet-500",
toColor: "to-zinc-400",


});
```

RandomizeGradient Function:

```
const randomizeTextGradient = () => {
    const randomDirection =
      gradientDirections[Math.floor(Math.random() * gradientDirections.length)]
        .value;
    const randomFromColor =
      fromArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * fromArray.length)].value;
    const randomViaColor =
      viaArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * viaArray.length)].value;
    const randomToColor =
      toArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * toArray.length)].value;

    const newGradient = {
      direction: randomDirection,
      fromColor: randomFromColor,
      viaColor: randomViaColor,
      toColor: randomToColor,
    };

    setGradient(newGradient);
      };
```

TextGradient.tsx:

```
 <section className="text-white bg-transparent border-t border-b border-zinc-800 my-6">
    <div className="py-4 mx-auto flex items-center gap-4 justify-between">
      <div className="flex gap-2">
        <button
          className="focus:outline-none p-2 bg-zinc-900 border rounded-md border-zinc-700 hover:bg-zinc-700"
          onClick={randomizeTextGradient}
        >
          <svg
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            className="w-5 h-5 text-white"
            fill="#fff"
            viewBox="0 0 256 256"
          >
            <path d="M197.67,186.37a8,8,0,0,1,0,11.29C196.58,198.73,170.82,224,128,224c-37.39,0-64.53-22.4-80-39.85V208a8,8,0,0,1-16,0V160a8,8,0,0,1,8-8H88a8,8,0,0,1,0,16H55.44C67.76,183.35,93,208,128,208c36,0,58.14-21.46,58.36-21.68A8,8,0,0,1,197.67,186.37ZM216,40a8,8,0,0,0-8,8V71.85C192.53,54.4,165.39,32,128,32,85.18,32,59.42,57.27,58.34,58.34a8,8,0,0,0,11.3,11.34C69.86,69.46,92,48,128,48c35,0,60.24,24.65,72.56,40H168a8,8,0,0,0,0,16h48a8,8,0,0,0,8-8V48A8,8,0,0,0,216,40Z"></path>
          </svg>
        </button>
        <CopyToClipboard
          text={`${gradient.direction} ${gradient.fromColor} ${gradient.viaColor} ${gradient.toColor} bg-clip-text text-transparent`}
          onCopy={() => setShowNotification(true)}
        >
          <button className="focus:outline-none p-2 bg-zinc-900 border rounded-md border-zinc-700 hover:bg-zinc-700">
            <svg
              className="w-5 h-5 text-blue-500"
              fill="#fff"
              aria-hidden="true"
              xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
              viewBox="0 0 20 14"
            >
              <path d="M9.782.72a4.773 4.773 0 0 0-4.8 4.173 3.43 3.43 0 0 1 2.741-1.687c1.689 0 2.974 1.972 3.758 2.587a5.733 5.733 0 0 0 5.382.935c2-.638 2.934-2.865 3.137-3.921-.969 1.379-2.44 2.207-4.259 1.231C14.488 3.365 13.551.6 9.782.72ZM4.8 6.979A4.772 4.772 0 0 0 0 11.151a3.43 3.43 0 0 1 2.745-1.687c1.689 0 2.974 1.972 3.758 2.587a5.733 5.733 0 0 0 5.382.935c2-.638 2.933-2.865 3.137-3.921-.97 1.379-2.44 2.208-4.259 1.231C9.51 9.623 8.573 6.853 4.8 6.979Z" />
            </svg>
          </button>
        </CopyToClipboard>
      </div>
      <div className="flex items-center gap-4">
        <div className="relative">
          <div className="">
            <select
              value={gradient.direction}
              onChange={(e) =>
                setGradient((prevGradient) => ({
                  ...prevGradient,
                  direction: e.target.value,
                }))
              }
              className="relative w-full cursor-default rounded-md bg-zinc-800 py-1.5 pl-3 pr-10 text-left text-white shadow-sm ring-1 ring-inset border-none ring-zinc-700 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 sm:text-sm sm:leading-6"
            >
              {gradientDirections.map((direction, index) => (
                <option key={index} value={direction.value}>
                  {direction.label}
                </option>
              ))}
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>

        {/* do the same for other selects */}
        <div className="relative">
          <div className="">
            <select
              value={gradient.fromColor}
              onChange={(e) =>
                setGradient((prevGradient) => ({
                  ...prevGradient,
                  fromColor: e.target.value,
                }))
              }
              className="relative w-full cursor-default rounded-md bg-zinc-800 py-1.5 pl-3 pr-10 text-left text-white shadow-sm ring-1 ring-inset border-none ring-zinc-700 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 sm:text-sm sm:leading-6"
            >
              {fromArray.map((gradient, index) => (
                <option key={index} value={gradient.value}>
                  {gradient.label}
                </option>
              ))}
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className="relative">
          <div className="">
            <select
              value={gradient.viaColor}
              onChange={(e) =>
                setGradient((prevGradient) => ({
                  ...prevGradient,
                  viaColor: e.target.value,
                }))
              }
              className="relative w-full cursor-default rounded-md bg-zinc-800 py-1.5 pl-3 pr-10 text-left text-white shadow-sm ring-1 ring-inset border-none ring-zinc-700 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 sm:text-sm sm:leading-6"
            >
              {viaArray.map((gradient, index) => (
                <option key={index} value={gradient.value}>
                  {gradient.label}
                </option>
              ))}
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className="relative">
          <div className="">
            <select
              value={gradient.toColor}
              onChange={(e) =>
                setGradient((prevGradient) => ({
                  ...prevGradient,
                  toColor: e.target.value,
                }))
              }
              className="relative w-full cursor-default rounded-md bg-zinc-800 py-1.5 pl-3 pr-10 text-left text-white shadow-sm ring-1 ring-inset border-none ring-zinc-700 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 sm:text-sm sm:leading-6"
            >
              {toArray.map((gradient, index) => (
                <option key={index} value={gradient.value}>
                  {gradient.label}
                </option>
              ))}
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <div>
        <PreviewText gradient={gradient} />
  </div>
```

In case you're curious - here's how I'm generating the classes:

```
    const colors = [
    "slate",
    "gray",
    "zinc",
    "neutral",
    "stone",
    "red",
    "orange",
    "amber",
    "yellow",
    "lime",
    "green",
    "emerald",
    "teal",
    "cyan",
    "sky",
    "blue",
    "indigo",
    "violet",
    "purple",
    "fuchsia",
    "pink",
    "rose",
  ];

  const numbers = [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900];

  let fromArray = [];
  let viaArray = [];
  let toArray = [];

  colors.forEach((color) => {
    numbers.forEach((number) => {
      let fromValueLabel = `from-${color}-${number}`;
      let viaValueLabel = `via-${color}-${number}`;
      let toValueLabel = `to-${color}-${number}`;
      fromArray.push({ value: fromValueLabel, label: fromValueLabel });
      viaArray.push({ value: viaValueLabel, label: viaValueLabel });
      toArray.push({ value: toValueLabel, label: toValueLabel });
    });
  });
```

I've been trying to fix this for 2 days now but no luck. Some help would be greatly appreciated. I've tested this code in both, NextJS AND React Vite.

Comment: Read this part https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names

Answer (score 0):

As @Danila mentioned, you are not quite following the documentation for dynamic class names. The main point from the docs is:

Don’t construct class names dynamically

```html
<div class="text-{{ error ? 'red' : 'green' }}-600"></div>
```

In the example above, the strings text-red-600 and text-green-600 do not exist, so Tailwind will not generate those classes.

Instead, make sure any class names you’re using exist in full:

Always use complete class names

```html
<div class="{{ error ? 'text-red-600' : 'text-green-600' }}"></div>
```